# Query native Android FourSquare application

Tags: android, api, native, foursquare

Is it possible to query the native FourSquare application installed on the device directly on the device without any web-queries? I am interested to know where the user is currently checked-in.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to launch the foursquare app:

```
Context mContext = context;  // your activity/context
Intent intentFourSquare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.foursquare.com/user?uid=XXXX"));

List<ResolveInfo> listResolver = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intentFourSquare, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo ri : listResolver)
{
        if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains(".foursquared"))
        {
            intentFourSquare.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name);
            mContext.startActivity(intentFourSquare);
            return;
        }
}

// if we've made it here, we didn't find the Intent we were looking for
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Foursquare app not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

though this doesn't address your real question of "where the user is currently checked-in", check with foursquare for a web api for this.

Comment: I do not want to start the app itself, and as said, I do not want to make a web request since the information should already be available on the device.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the user is checked in, have the user authorize your app ( https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth ) and call the relevant API endpoint ( https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins )

Comment: I do not want to make web request if not necessary. Is there no way to query the information from the native app?

Comment: There is no way. We require apps to authorize your app in order for your app to access their private information. We use OAuth2 + our API in order to enforce this access control.